# Can we create endless session in php?

Tags: php, session

Normally a php session expires when the user closes the browser. Is is possible to create a session in php that never expires, doesn't matter how many times user closes and restart the browser?

Thanks

Comment: That's really not a good idea. Each active session takes up resources on your server. Having them time-out after a while is required in order to prevent thousands of sessions for inactive users from clogging up your server. Use cookies instead, if you must do something like this.

Comment: @Spudley: or save the session data in a database using [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Comment: @fireeyedboy - wherever you save it, if you never let it time out, then you're going to run out of resource at some point or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not strictly endless, but you can set the cookie lifetime to two years or so which comes pretty close:

- [`session.cookie-lifetime` ini setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)
- [`session_set_cookie_params()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function to set them programmatically.

The session cookie won't be deleted then if the user closes the browser.

Take care that your session data store [keeps the data as well that long](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime). This is important. And keep in mind that you need to store all user's data for this large time-span, so you should have enough space available.

This does not work at all if the user disables cookies in her or his browser.

Comment: using COOKIES is the only way really, and you can set your site to renew the COOKIE for another X years each time it loads, creating a form of perpetuity

Comment: please guide me how the code will look like. Is cookie/session same thing in php?

Comment: Its not helping in Internet explorer 9 because by default it does not take store cookies...so after i close IE and restart it..it is not able to retain the cookie...i guess because it is not actually storing the cookie. I have also unchecked delete browsing history on exit, but of no help. I want to store the user information which persists even after user closes the browser and restarts it. Can we do this in php by using any means...??

Comment: If the browser is not storing cookies, it's the browsers decision. The server (PHP) has not influence to this. It might be a technical speciality with the IE9 here however (I'm not supporting MS products specifically, so don't ask me) and you might find other questions here related to it that are specifically about IE9 and storing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It is never endless. But you can set cookies/session for more than 10 years in future. However, your server is gathering more and more session files, be aware of that. I collected almost a million files in my tmp directory

Answer (score -1):

No, the best you can do is set a cookie with an expiration date far in the future.

Even then, the user can just delete it without even closing the browser or leaving the site, so don't rely on it.