# How to never logout with PHP Session?

Tags: php, nginx

i have a simple login system based on `$_SESSION`.

But it logged out after a few minutes or something... How can i complete disable this?

I tried to change php.ini to

`session.gc_maxlifetime = ‭2592000‬0
session.cookie_lifetime = ‭2592000‬0`

for 30 days but doesnt work

I use NGINX and the site is PHP alone, without any framework

What i must change in NGINX or PHP? :/

That `session.gc_maxlifetime = ‭2592000‬0, 
session.cookie_lifetime = ‭2592000‬0` was what i found about that... and i tried it but it doesnt help.
Anyone can help me to make session never kicked/logged out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663089/can-we-create-endless-session-in-php

Comment: do you have `session_start()` at the top on every script requiring sessions?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Yes `ob_start();
session_start(); `

Comment: check out `print_r(phpinfo());`

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi What did i need to check? Session is enabled. cookie_lifetime is 2592000‬0

Comment: @FurkanKolcu I setup cookie_lifetime and gc_maxlifetime to 30days but doesnt help :/

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi or did i must change something in nginx?